# JSF 404 Error page doesn't build component tree

Tags: jsf, http-status-code-404

i try to implement a custom 404 error page in a webproject with glassfish.

I added the error page tag to web.xml like this

```
    <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
```

Then i built up my 404 page like that

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
  <h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="template/common/commonLayout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
                Text ...
                <h:commandButton value="index" />
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The redirect to that page works fine, but all the components don't get rendered by the container so i get that html output.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="template/common/commonLayout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
                Text...
                <h:commandButton value="index" />
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

Someone got a clue how i can fix that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. i just forgot that i had a servlet mapping on /faces/* and not on /*.xhtml so i had to add /faces/ to the error page mapping